# Lebesgue measure of the given set

Tags: real-analysis

The Lebesgue measure of the set

$A$={$0<x\leq 1 : x \sin({\frac{\pi}{2x}})\geq 0$} is

1. $0$
2. $1$
3. $\ln2$
4. $1-\ln$$\sqrt2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use Dominated convergence theorem, and Abel's theorem for interchanging integral and sum of infinite series: $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2x}\right) \geq 0 \to \dfrac{\pi}{2x} \in [2n\pi,(2n+1)\pi]\to 4n \leq \frac{1}{x} \leq 4n+2 \to x \in [\frac{1}{4n+2}, \frac{1}{4n}]\to A = \displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [\frac{1}{4n+2}, \frac{1}{4n}]\to m(A) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{4n}-\frac{1}{4n+2}\right) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \left(x^{4n-1} - x^{4n+1}\right)dx = \displaystyle \int_{0}^1 \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(x^{4n-1}-x^{4n+1}\right)dx=...=1-\ln 2$

Comment: The answer is option(4).

Comment: How you find the sum. I can not understand it. Please clear it..